# Spring Redis Delete does not delete key

Tags: spring, redis

I am trying to delete a redis key but for some reason it is not delete but also not throwing an exception. Here is my code to delete:

```
import com.example.service.CustomerService;
import com.example.model.Customer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.*;

@Service
public class RedisCustomerService implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate; 

    private String uniqueIdKey = "customerId";

    private BigInteger uniqueId() {
        long uniqueId = this.redisTemplate.opsForValue().increment(uniqueIdKey, 1);
        return BigInteger.valueOf(uniqueId);
    }

    private String lastNameKey(BigInteger id) {
        return "customer:ln:" + id;
    }

    private String firstNameKey(BigInteger id) {
        return "customer:fn:" + id;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCustomer(BigInteger id) {
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().getOperations().delete(String.valueOf(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the monitor command from redis-cli to see which commands are sent to the Redis server. http://redis.io/commands/monitor

Comment: is your redis a master instance? Your behaviour would happen if you try to delete a key on a slave instance.

Answer (score 56):

ValueOperations does NOT have *delete* method. So the following won't work:

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().delete(key);
```

Try

```
redisTemplate.delete(key);
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative technique for deleting using `ValueOperations` is to set an empty value that will expire almost immediately. Redis will handle the eviction itself.

For example, you can set a value like this:

```
valueOperations.set("key", "value");
```

When you want to delete you can then do something like this:

```
valueOperations.set("key", "", 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

**It's essential that the key is the same in both operations**

Comment: A very helpful solution if you're a fan of super awkward race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Before spring boot 2, if you didn't specify a serializer when building resttemplate, on redis you see keys like this:

> "xac\xed\x00\x05t\x008mx.company.support.catalog.dao.keys"

But when trying to delete it with `redisTemplate.delete(key)` the key is not erased

One easy way is to get the key in byte and proceed to delete it.

Example in your class:

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

public boolean deleteKeyByPattern(String pattern) {
    Set<byte[]> patternResultConf = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().keys(pattern.getBytes());
    if(Objects.nonNull(patternResultConf) && !patternResultConf.isEmpty()) {
        redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().del(patternResultConf.toArray(new byte[0][]));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void deleteCustomer(BigInteger id) {
        redisTemplate.execute(new RedisCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public String doInRedis(RedisConnection redisConnection) throws DataAccessException {
                        redisConnection.del(redisTemplate.getStringSerializer().serialize(String.valueOf(id)));
                        return null;
                }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void deleteCustomer(BigInteger id) {
        redisTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.delete(String.valueOf(id));
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no getOperation to use :

```
@Override
public void deleteCustomer(BigInteger id) {
    redisTemplate.opsForValue().delete(String.valueOf(id));
}
```