# Spring boot + Redis - Generating a strange key

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jedis

I am using Spring-boot + Redis to store my data on cache.

My Controller has this configuration:

```
public class CacheController {    
@GetMapping("/{key}")
    @Cacheable(value = "myCacheValue", keyGenerator = "customKeyGenerator")
    public String getByKey(@PathVariable("key") String key) {
        return key + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

My customKeyGenerator is:

```
public class CustomKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(target.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .append("-")
                .append(method.getName());

        if (params != null) {
            for (Object param : params) {
                sb.append("-")
                        .append(param.getClass().getSimpleName())
                        .append(":").append(param);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

When I connect in my redis I have this key:

```
1 - redis-cli --raw
KEYS *
myCacheValue~keys
��t$CacheController-getByKey-String:key9

2 - redis-cli
KEYS *
myCacheValue~keys
\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00$CacheController-getByKey-String:key9
```

Why this characters are present before "CacheController"?

**Note:** My key Generator starts with my Class name.

I would like that my key name be only this:
CacheController-getByKey-String:myKey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem.
I was searching and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324717/spring-boot-caching-with-redis-key-have-xac-xed-x00-x05t-x00-x06).

I changed my code for use some properties of RedisTemplate:

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
    RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);

    configureSerializers(redisTemplate);

    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = (JedisConnectionFactory) cf;
    JedisPoolConfig actualPoolConfig = jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig();
    jedisConnectionFactory.setPoolConfig(createJedisPoolConfig(actualPoolConfig));

    return redisTemplate;
}

private void configureSerializers(RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate) {
    RedisSerializer<String> serializerKey = new StringRedisSerializer();
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(serializerKey);
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(serializerKey);

    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<Object> jackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    om.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
    om.configure(
            DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    jackson2JsonRedisSerializer.setObjectMapper(om);

    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(jackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
}
```

The problem is because the default Serializer is "JdkSerializationRedisSerializer", now I am using "StringRedisSerializer" to generate a key.
To generate value I am using "Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer" to transform my data in JsonValue.

Now, my keys does not have the "strange" characters.

Answer (score 1):

from the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-caching-provider-redis), you can use a `RedisCacheConfiguration` Bean to customize your `redisCacheManager`:

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration() {
    return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig();
    }
}
```

and the default configuration is:

```
    public static RedisCacheConfiguration defaultCacheConfig() {

    DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();

    registerDefaultConverters(conversionService);

    return new RedisCacheConfiguration(Duration.ZERO, true, true, CacheKeyPrefix.simple(),
            SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer()),// this will use string as the key serializer
            SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer()), conversionService);
}
```