# Nifi+Redis generate a strange cache key/ val - how to properly serialize/ deserialize?

Tags: java, serialization, redis, apache-nifi, spring-data-redis

My Nifi processor implementation is generating a strange cache key and value, something like '\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x06' is prepended to each key/ val.
For example, inserting 'key':'val' generates "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x03key":"\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x03val".

Nifi uses spring data in the background, issue described here:

[Spring boot + Redis - Generating a strange key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291548/spring-boot-redis-generating-a-strange-key?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Spring boot caching with redis,key have \xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x06](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324717/spring-boot-caching-with-redis-key-have-xac-xed-x00-x05t-x00-x06?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Nifi processor is just java code that overrides provided method.

I don't have spring config available to edit or spring data classes, that's all done within Nifi's implementation.
All I have, and have to provide is serializer and deserializer:

```
void serialize(T value, OutputStream output) throws SerializationException, IOException;
T deserialize(byte[] input) throws DeserializationException, IOException;
```

For example getAndPutIfAbsent method looks like this:

```
cache.getAndPutIfAbsent(key, value, keySerializer, valueSerializer, valueDeserializer);
```

My byte serialization/ deserialization is simple:

```
 public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        os.writeObject(obj);
        return out.toByteArray();
    }

    public static Object deserialize(byte[] data) {
        if (data == null || data.length == 0) return null;
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            return is.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This generates keys/ vals with prepended value. Put and get do work, I can get the value that I previously put using the same serializer and deserializer, except in one case.

I have few caches and they all use same object serializer/ deserializer pasted above. As I mentioned everything works except one cache where I use scan method (paging through all keys). On key deserialization it throws: java invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF. I don't get it why other caches work but this one throws exception, they are all serializing/ deserializing the same.

My goal is to get keys/ vals without prepended chars and working consistently. I can not tinker with spring configs and classes. How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Using following de/serialization for strings fixed both issues:

```
value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
new String(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Not sure why, but it works now.