# Java creating Redis key and content with strange characters

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I'm creating a new Redis key (and content) with the following code:

```
private static final String KEY_ESTADOS = "estados";
private HashOperations<String, String, Object> hashOperations;

public void add(final Estado estado) {
    hashOperations.put(KEY_ESTADOS, estado.getSigla(), estado);
}
```

Instead of create a key "estados" on Redis, it's creating a key name ""\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\aestados"

[image]

The key content is also with strange characters:
[image]

Anybody knows how to fix this?

The Estados class implements Serializable but I would like save it's content in pure json so I could change HashOperations to  instead of . What do you recommend to serialize to json and deserialize it back to object?

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer to convert to json and set valueSerializer.  [This blog post may help you](http://oppalove.com/2017/03/06/spring-boot-redis-json-examlpe/?i=1)

Comment: That "blog post" is a dangerous link.

Answer (score 12):

To solve the problem about the redis key, hash key and content value I had to add the following lines on RedisTemplate method:

```
template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using Socket and I fixed it due replacing `ObjectOutputStream` with `OutputStream`. Maybe that helps.